# Groups of MPI do not assign correct rank of processors

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have the following MPI/fortran code to create two groups one which 
contains the first 2/3 of the total number of processors and the second
which includes the rest 1/3. It compiles without problem but when I 
print out the new rank (in the recently created group), only the second
group displays the correct ranks, the processes in the first group 
shows negative numbers.

Do you have any comment about this issue?
Thanks.

```
program test

    implicit none
    include "mpif.h"
    integer, allocatable :: rs_use(:),ks_use(:)
    integer numnodes,myid,mpi_err
    integer ijk,new_group,old_group,num_used,used_id
    integer proc_rs,proc_ks
    integer RSPA_COMM_WORLD    !Real Space communicator
    integer KSPA_COMM_WORLD    !Recip. Space communicator

! initialize mpi
    call MPI_INIT( mpi_err )
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numnodes, mpi_err )
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, mpi_err)

    proc_rs = 2*numnodes/3            !Nr. of processors for Real Space
    proc_ks = numnodes - proc_rs      !Nr. of processors for Recip.  Space

    write(6,*) 'processors rs',proc_rs,'ks',proc_ks

! get our old group from MPI_COMM _WORLD
    call MPI_COMM_GROUP(MPI_COMM_WORLD,old_group,mpi_err)

! Real Space group  that will contain 2*N/3 processors
    allocate(rs_use(0:proc_rs-1))
    do ijk=0,proc_rs-1
        rs_use(ijk)=ijk
    enddo
    call MPI_GROUP_INCL(old_group,proc_rs,rs_use,new_group,mpi_err)
! create the new communicator
    call MPI_COMM_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,new_group,RSPA_COMM_WORLD, mpi_err)
! test to see if I am part of new_group.
    call MPI_GROUP_RANK(new_group,used_id, mpi_err)

! Recip.  Space group  that will contain N/3 processors
    allocate(ks_use(proc_rs:numnodes-1))
    do ijk=proc_rs,numnodes-1
        ks_use(ijk)=ijk
    enddo
    call MPI_GROUP_INCL(old_group,proc_ks,ks_use,new_group,mpi_err)
! create the new communicator
    call MPI_COMM_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,new_group,KSPA_COMM_WORLD, mpi_err)
! test to see if I am part of new_group.
    call MPI_GROUP_RANK(new_group,used_id, mpi_err)

    if(used_id==0) write(6,*) 'group ',used_id,myid


end program test
```

Comment: You don't test the success of any of your calls to MPI routines.  Nor the success of the `allocate` statements.  Why should I not conclude that one of those calls fails silently ?

Comment: Hi, I tested both allocate and MPI routines, thanks for the suggestion. However, I still have the issue, used_id for the firs group prints out negative numbers.

Comment: @innoSPG has the correct answer, but I'll offer two more general suggestions: (1) In modern fortran, it is *strongly* suggested you use `use mpi` rather than `include "mpif.h"`, and let the compiler find entire classes of potential problems for you at compile time.  (2) in this case, where you're partitioning an existing communicator into two non-overlapping subsets, using [`MPI_Comm_split`](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_split_type.3.php) is easier.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that only processes that belong to the group have an id in that group. What you have to do is to set `new_group` only in the appropriate group of processes and check the new id after you have include each process in its new group. For example, use a temp variable `tmp_group` to call `MPI_COMM_CREATE` and assign it only to the process of the group. For the first call to `MPI_COMM_CREATE`, you do this:

```
call MPI_GROUP_RANK(tmp_group,used_id, mpi_err)
if(myid<proc_rs) new_group = tmp_group
```

For the second call to `MPI_COMM_CREATE`, you do do this:

```
call MPI_GROUP_RANK(tmp_group,used_id, mpi_err)
if(myid>=proc_rs) new_group = tmp_group
```

After all of this, you can check the new rank for all:

```
call MPI_GROUP_RANK(new_group,used_id, mpi_err)
```

If you choose to check the rank in the group right after you create the group, make sure that only processes belonging to the group call. But this is not a good idea, as you will possibly not save the new_group.